# Running a VBA function by clicking an Excel cell

Tags: excel, function, vba, hyperlink

When a specific cell is clicked, I need to run a function. The function is:

```
HighlightOnWebsite(url As String, phrase As String)
```

Basically, this function loads a Web Browser Control, brings up the requested page, and highlights the required phrases. The function works more ore less fine.

What I can't figure out is how to get certain cells to call this function.

Lets say each row has 3 cells which contain the following information:

```
url of some document | some important phrase | will contain call to function
```

Now, I need to scan the spreadsheet and in the third column of each row, make a clickable cell which calls a function like HighlightOnWebsite(A1,A2).

Would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to scan the worksheet.

Create, in each cell of the third column, a static hyperlink that links to that same cell.
Then have a handler in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
  If Target.Range.Column = 3 Then
    HighlightOnWebsite Target.Range.Offset(0, -2).Value, Target.Range.Offset(0, -1).Value
  End If
End Sub
```